# Caption placement for double column figure in Elsevier document

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, els-cas

I am unable to get my caption to be properly (left) spaced below a figure in a double column document.  This is using the Elsevier double-column template.  No errors or warnings are present but the placement of the caption is to the right quite a bit, as shown below.  The caption is supposed to start at the left edge of the figure.  I've tried using \usepackage{caption}, \captionsetup, and a number of other methods through Google-fu.

[image: Caption mis-placed]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure*}[] 
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Diagram_v4.eps}
  \caption{\label{fig:Prototype_view} Caption stuff.Caption stuff.Caption stuff.Caption stuff.Caption stuff.Caption stuff.Caption stuff.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: If I compile [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/YqZtP9i7) (I had to add `natbib` and `\maketitle`) then the output [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjX78.png). Please edit your code so that when compiled it shows the issue. You can start with your actual document (and replace the text by `\lipsum` and the picture with `example-image`) instead of writing an example from scratch.

Comment: I updated my MWE with only the code in my actual document.  The caption is still off.

Comment: Unrelated: don't put the label in the caption, it is a separate command that is put after the caption command is finished.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you remove the empty `[]` after `\begin{figure*}` the caption should be fine.

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple!

Answer (score 0):

Add `\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\FullWidth}{\textwidth}}` at the code header to fix the `\textwidth` length.

Then you can control better your floats:
`\begin{figure}[h!, align=\flushleft, width=\textwidth]`